# How to tell if I'm on a Mac or iOS

Tags: python, ios, macos, operating-system

I'd like to be able to do stuff like

```py
from os import system
system(f'say "hello world"')
```

But this only works on Mac, not iOS.

I know I can detect a Mac by using `platform.system()`, but that doesn't tell me Mac vs iOS.

I've also noticed that `platform().platform()` has the substring "iPad" in it when I'm running on an iPad, but I'm not sure if that's documented/can be relied on, or if on an iPhone it will do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following code.

```
from sys import platform
print(platform)
```

[image]